# Views rewrite output including the wrapper divs?

Tags: views, entities

I have 3 fields in a view and I want to rewrite the output in a fourth field.
like this

```
[field1][field2][field3][field4]
```

But I want to have a wrapper div around each field like in the field settings.
The problem is I could do something like this:

```
<div class="mywrapper">
  <div class="field1">[field1]</div>
  <div class="field3">[field2]</div>
  <div class="field3">[field3]</div>
  <div class="field4">[field4]</div>
</div>
```

But with this even if the field is empty the divs with the css classes will stay alive.
I dont want that. If the field is empty dont display it with the `<div>`.

If I just display the field, there are no wrappers at all.

Comment: I am not 100% sure but print $view or $output you will find the html wrappers as well. (check source code if wrappers are not visible on browser)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. I use the modul [views_fieldsets](http://drupal.org/project/views_fieldsets).